# Value is not getting selected from the select field

Tags: php, select

I am trying to get a time- value from a select form.I could not see any errors in the code,tried to change all class names and variables ,but still value is not get selected.(I could not see the selected value after submitting the form)

**Code is added as follows:**

```
  public function storeproTime()
  {
  echo $value = esc_attr( get_option( 'email_time' ) );
    $start = strtotime('12:00 AM');
    $end   = strtotime('11:59 PM');
    echo '<select style="width:85px;" name="email_time" id="select1" value ="' . $value . '" 
    >';
    
        for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++) 
        {
        
            for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30)
            {
                
                 $hours_minutes = 
             str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
                
                
        
                
                echo "<option  value='". $hours_minutes ."' >".$hours_minutes."</option>";
            }
            } 
         echo '</select>';
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a value be automatically selected, you need to add the `selected` attribute to the `<option>` element, you don't put it in the `value` attribute of the `<select>`.

```
public function storeproTime()
{
    $value = esc_attr( get_option( 'email_time' ) );
    $start = strtotime('12:00 AM');
    $end   = strtotime('11:59 PM');
    echo '<select style="width:85px;" name="email_time" id="select1" >';
    
    for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++) 
    {
        for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30)
        {
            $hours_minutes = str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $selected = $hours_minutes == $value ? 'selected' : '';
            echo "<option  value='". $hours_minutes ."' " . $selected . ">".$hours_minutes."</option>";
        }
    } 
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Comment: That was a catch !, and it worked 
Thank you  Barmar

Comment: @Pranavmtn See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work